# Google spreadsheets: filter facebook comment data based on status_id

Tags: facebook, google-sheets

Sorry if this has been asked before, or if it is too basic. I am not a native coder, nor a spreadsheet expert.
I have two CSV files of data from a public facebook page which have been imported into a GSpreadsheet. One contains all the posts the page has made. The other contains the comments. They share a common field "status_id". 
I was able to filter out the posts to the relevant ones for my project. **I want to filter out the comments to only have the ones which share a status_id with the relevant posts.** I have tried a vlookup, but do not know how to modify it to give multiple rows with the same value. Can anyone please advise? Thank you.

Edit: [Link added](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xcFnFzdYKZTJmfdpaQHsi45J2QYAfeTnIeGkCk4O_eY/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

just wrap your `vlookup` in an `arrayformula`.
Check the doc here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275